# Extract point data to polygon features

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, point, extract

I am trying to import data from a point that lies on a certain polygon feature (or raster). As an output I would like the polygon feature to have the point data as a new field in the attribute table. How can this be done in QGIS?

Comment: You want to have the points information in that polygon ?

Comment: Hey Mike, did you try to do an intersection? I mean intersecting your polygon layers with your points?

Comment: Hi, i think you are looking for "spatial join". You can try to google this and you will have plenty of helpfull tuto about this.

Comment: You mention "polygon feature (or raster)". Vectors and rasters use different sets of tools, so applying point data to a raster would be an entirely different question. Or did you want to apply raster data to a point? That would be another different question.

Comment: Thank you all very much! Join attributes by location was what I needed eventually!